# Show an identity involving a sum of arctangents of algebraic expressions

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that
>   $$
> 2\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2} - x + b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} + \tan^{-1}\frac{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b\sqrt{x^2+a^2} + a^2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b} = n\pi .
> $$

I tried using $$ x= a \tan \theta ,\; b= a \sin\phi,$$
but then calculations are not working out; that is,
I am not able to further simplify.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [mathjax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: after substituting what i said, the further calculations are tedious. some body else commented to take tan’s of all three terms , tried with that but still not getting answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the roots of $\tan x$ are precisely the integer multiples $n \pi$ of $\pi$, applying $\tan$ to be sides gives that the equation is equivalent to
$$\phantom{(ast)} \qquad \tan[2 \arctan A + \arctan B + \arctan C] = 0 \qquad (\ast)$$
for 
$$
A := \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} - x - b}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}} , \qquad
B := \frac{x \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} + a^2} , \qquad
C := \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b} .
$$

Iterating the tangent sum identity gives a formula for the tangent of the sum of four angles:
$$\tan(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 + \alpha_4)
= \frac{\sum_i \tan \alpha_i - \sum_{i < j < k} \tan \alpha_i \tan \alpha_j \tan \alpha_k}
{1 - \sum_{i < j} \alpha_i \alpha_j + \alpha_1 \alpha_2 \alpha_3 \alpha_4} .$$
So, we can evaluate the left-hand side of $(\ast)$ by setting $\tan \alpha_1 = \tan \alpha_2 = A, \tan \alpha_3 = B, \tan \alpha_4 = C$. Since we only want to check that the sum vanishes, it's show that the numerator is zero, that is, that
$$2 A + B + C - A^2 B - A^2 C - 2 ABC = 0 .$$ Simplifying is a little tedious but straightforward.

Comment: no. i tried. not able to do

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by no. The method certainly works, and I even double-checked it with a CAS when writing up the answer. From the end of the answer it's just fortitude and mechanical algebra.

Comment: the mechanical algebra which you are saying, i tried but the calculations are too tedious

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Write the equation as $\tan^{-1}\frac{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b\sqrt{x^2+a^2} + a^2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b} = n\pi - 2\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2} - x + b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} $
- Apply $\tan$ on both sides and use $\tan (n \pi - 2\alpha) = -\tan 2\alpha$
- Resolve the tangents on the left using $\tan \beta + \tan \gamma =\frac{\tan \beta + \tan \gamma}{1- \tan \beta \tan \gamma}$ and on the right using $\tan(2\alpha) = \frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}$
- Now you are left with an equation consisting of only algebraic fractions in the variables $a,b,x$

Comment: does not gets solved.